# How can I specify the correct 'return type'?

Tags: c

I have a `C` program which produces the error message:

> p3-static-store-class.c:5:1 warning: return type defaults to 'int' [- 
>       Wimplicit-int] main()

with warning highlighted and a arrow highlighting the m in `main()`. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* function declaration */
void func(void);
static int count = 5; /* global variable */
main()
{
    while(count--)
    {
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}

/* function definition */
void func(void)
{
    static int i = 5; /* local static variable */
    i++;
    printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

My attempt at specifying the return type produced a list of error messages, and `C` syntax is nothing like what I'm used to - so what is the remedy for this?

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: *"C syntax is nothing like what I'm used to - so what is the remedy for this?"* - old wisdom would say that you should learn C syntax.

Comment: You know how it should look like with function `func`. What is the problem applying the same knowledge to function `main`?

Comment: @Groo I have a weird feeling I was in the process of doing that...

Comment: Btw, the only purpose of a `static` is to make your variable accessible from other .c file you'll be using to compile your program.

Comment: @Nofix You mean the opposite, I guess. Adding `static` makes it non-accessible for other .c files.

Comment: @Gerhardh Indeed, I meant the opposite, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the return type for `main()`

```
int main()
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly state that `main()` takes no arguments

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: If your program runs in a hosted environment, arguments to main could be useful. For example filenames

The exact declaration of main looks like this:

int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

Comment: @Mike If the program does not use any parameters, there is no need to have a parameter to `main`. Therefore `int main (void)` is a valid version as well. But the empty parameter list is deprecated nowadays.